# Fetch and display image from MS SQL in Android

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, sqlite, bitmap

I am fetching the image (datatype is image) from the MS SQL database and the format i am getting is as follows.

```
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
```

I tried to convert it into bitmap image and i am getting error message.  Can anyone please help me figure out the issue?

This is the code used for converting to image.

```
byte[] blob = string.getBytes(); 
Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
imageview.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

**String is the data from image field of SQL database.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Error is  D/skia(1427): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will help,in imgByte  you are getting a long String in format as   shown by you

```
         String imgByte ="your string in question";

        try{
            byte [] encodeByte= Base64.decode(imgByte,Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();

        }
```

while Storing im encoding it

```
            Bitmap photo = bitmap;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
            byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            db.upDateConatct(worldPopulation,worldPopulation.getRank(),encodedImage);
```

Comment: I tried this code and don't work. Seems like the code is not encoded using base64. Can you please try the code and see if its working for you?

Comment: Bitmap photo = bitmap;
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: @Rzk i have working code and have tested it please can you post your code so that i can see where is problem

Comment: Actually, the images are converted and stored in MS SQL Database from a C# application and the datatype in SQL database is Image. 

The image is stored after converting it into byte array.

Comment: This is my code
`byte [] encodeByte= string.getBytes();
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

**string is already posted in the question. This is the string which i get from SQL database and the datatype of the field is 'Image'

Comment: what error you are getting while you used code that i posted

Comment: D/skia(1628): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: please post logcat

Comment: Code: `ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        String string = "_**As in the question**_";
        byte [] encodeByte= string.getBytes();
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

Logcat:
`03-29 05:53:15.389: D/skia(1674): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
03-29 05:53:15.859: D/gralloc_goldfish(1674): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.`

Comment: @Rzk i have again tested it string gives me long string s you have but it is working in my case,please make sure you have tried first portion of answer

Comment: delete that record and try with different String maybe string that you have is invalid

Comment: i have tried it deleting and adding new record. Please note that the string is the image data from the SQL Database. When i compared it with the image data from the android device, it has a big difference. The string in android starts with X'*****' where as SQL starts with 0x****.